# Model Post does not conform to Encodable

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm trying to implement pagination into my application but it requires me to conform my Post Model to Encodable. I've tried reading through the docs but I'm having a hard time understanding them and I'm worried that I could break my code if I mess something up. I thought it was as easy as adding "Encodable" to the properties next the struct name but I was wrong.

My Model is below

```
struct Post: Identifiable, Decodable, ScrollableData {
    @DocumentID var id: String?
    let caption: String
    let timestamp: Timestamp
    let photoUrl: String
    let uid: String
    var comments: Int
    var likes: Int
    var replyingTo: String?
    var edited: Bool?
    
    var user: User?
    var didFavourite: Bool? = false
    var didLike: Bool? = false
    
    var timestampString: String {
        let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
        formatter.allowedUnits = [.second, .minute, .hour, .day, .weekOfMonth]
        formatter.maximumUnitCount = 1
        formatter.unitsStyle = .abbreviated
        return formatter.string(from: timestamp.dateValue(), to: Date()) ?? ""
    }
    
    var detailedTimestampString: String {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "h:mm a · MM/dd/yyyy"
        return formatter.string(from: timestamp.dateValue())
    }
}
```

Guidance in the right direction or support is highly appreciated :)

Comment: Make sure user confirms too

Comment: @loremipsum ah could that be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

My user var wasn't conforming to Encodable, after adding the property to both my code now runs.